# How to ask for career advice?

Tags: discussion

Is there a way to ask some of the old timers on here for career advice? I'm looking to discuss with someone on here a method for picking career path within EE based on skill set and interest...

It's not really an appropriate question for meta but I know it's not an appropriate question for the forums.

Comment: "How do I do something on this site" is a perfect question for meta. I'm not sure what the 'right' answer is to your question though.

Comment: Career advice questions are not appropriate for Meta, if that's what you meant.  Kellenjb is correct that this question is perfect for Meta.

Comment: @Kevin Yes, that is what I meant. I guess I'll just try to hang out in the chat room or something

Comment: @JGord, i think people have bad flashbacks for chat, it is actually very well done and you can hold multiple conversations at once without much problem and if you want open other rooms for user specific talks.

Answer (score 4):

Career advice isn't a good fit for the main site.  Thanks for recognizing that, and bringing this here.

At present, we don't have a good location for Q&A about electrical engineering careers.  I don't think that this fits in well as a tag (because it's off topic for the site), I doubt that it would survive as a site on its own, and [careers.stackoverflow.com](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) isn't what you're looking for.

Your best option, then, (especially since you said "discussion") is going to be to [bring it to Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering).  The format is different, and traffic is lower, but most anything goes there.