# On which site can I ask questions on electronic engineering roles?

Tags: discussion, scope

In hardware engineering, there are many roles: for example PCB Design engineer, FPGA engineer etc.

Can we ask questions like:

- What are the roles and responsibilities of a FPGA engineer?
- What are the skills required for a PCB engineer?

on Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange?
If not, is there any other Stack Exchange site to ask such questions?

Comment: No one I guess. Quora is the popular platform for queries like that. Aaaaaaaaaand I personally don't like Quora.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd try on [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering). I don't think it would be well-received on the main site. For example, searching for [`engineer skill is:question`](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=engineer+skill+is%3Aquestion) will show a few similar questions, all of which are closed.

There also was a question about how to ask for career advices [here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/696/how-to-ask-for-career-advice), posted 10 years ago, and the answer was the same: chat.

Of course, chat drags much less people.

I also tried to check if there are other sites on the SE network where this kind of questions would be appropriate. The [workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) is dedicated to career-related topics, but it seems asking about skills required for a specific job is off-topic according to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/246026/325443) (written by an ex-mod of the workplace site). There is also a specific close-reason on this site that confirms it is off-topic: "*Questions asking for advice on a specific choice, such as what job to take or what skills to learn, are difficult to answer objectively and are rarely useful for anyone else. [...]*"

So, apart from chat, I don't think it can be asked anywhere on Stack Exchange. But I'm pretty sure there are discussion forums outside of SE where you could ask this.